# Magento multiple category images

Tags: category

Looking at this website: http://www.davidyurman.com/women/bracelets

I'm wondering how we can do something similar with specific regards to the large inline images   within Magento categories.

http://prntscr.com/42yqyg

At first, I thought it was simply a matter of displaying the category image that can be defined in admin in a different location. However, if you scroll down the page, you will notice there are several images defined for the category page.

So I think what this setup would entail is defining multiple images for the category, where each category image (image 1, image 2, image 3, etc) would show in a predefined location within the template.

So now my question is, does my idea of defining multiple images work and if so, what do you think the best way to execute upon this idea is?

I love the idea of not displaying products in a boring typical product grid. The larger inline images are a great way to break up the browsing pattern!

P.S. The use case would be Magento 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have three images. You can add more attributes to the category and then upload three images and fit them into the list.